# SQL Server Wildcard Search

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2014 and I'm getting incorrect results back from a `LIKE` expression. I'm trying to match this type of string `A-ABC123-AABB` where `ABC123` and `AABB` can be any length strings.

Here is the `LIKE` expression:

```
ID.name LIKE 'a-%-'+STR.STR
```

If the iteration has `STR` as a string with a prefixed dash and there exists an `STR` with no P, it will return the value with no dash.

How can I do strict matching so that it shows only the result with the dash, IF `STR` has a string?

Example:

`STR` table:

```
col     STR     Val
----------------
1       test    10
2       -test   12
```

`ID` table:

```
col     name
-----------------------
1       a-blah-test
2       a-blah--test
3       a-tst-test
```

Results:

```
name            val
--------------------
a-blah-test     10
a-blah--test    10
a-blah--test    12
```

Comment: Could you post some actual sample data, along with expected results please?

Comment: I've added an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might fix your problem here although I'm not sure it will handle all the general cases correctly.

```
ID.names LIKE 'P-%[^-]-'+ STR.STR
```

Comment: I used this and also added another case 'A-%[-][^-]'+STR.STR